# How can I generate relocatable- and absolute-objectcode?

Tags: object-code

If I have that C-Code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;

    int c = a + b;

    return c;
}
```

How can I generate for the upper example a:

- relocatable objectcode
- absolute objectcode

within Linux (Ubuntu) and the GNU gcc-compiler ?